# Selecting a point on GoogleMaps after clicking a button

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have this code:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 padding_all_2">
      <a href ="#" class="obj-1" id="obj-1"><div class="apartament_atrakcje">Atrakcja 1 pl</div></a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 padding_all_2">
      <a href ="#" class="obj-2" id="obj-2"><div class="apartament_atrakcje">Atrakcja 2 PL</div></a>
</div>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<script>
   window.onload = function () {
       var styles = [{"featureType":"all"}];
       var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
       var options = {
           mapTypeControlOptions: {
               mapTypeIds: ['Styled']
           },
           center: new google.maps.LatLng(11, 22),
           zoom: 15,
           disableDefaultUI: true,
           mapTypeId: 'Styled'
       };
       marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           map:map,
       });
       var div = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
       var map = new google.maps.Map(div, options);
       var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, { name: 'Styled' });

       var markers = [
                        [
                          'Atrakcja 1 pl', 
                           51.73925413, 
                           19.51309225, 
                           'Atrakcja 1 pl', 
                           '#'
                         ],
                         [
                           'Atrakcja 2 PL', 
                            53.41475000, 
                            14.60220358, 
                           'Atrakcja 2 PL', 
                           '#'
                         ],
                     ];
       var infoWindow= new google.maps.InfoWindow({maxWidth:600}),
           marker, i,
           image = 'http://localhost/assets/poi.png';

       for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
           var beach = markers[i];
           var position = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);
           bounds.extend(position);
           marker = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: position,
               map: map,
               icon: image,
               title: beach[0],
               myurl: beach[4]
           });

           google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
               return function() {
                   infoWindow.setContent('<a href="'+marker['myurl']+'">'+marker['title']+'</a>');
                   infoWindow.open(map, marker);
               }
           })(marker, i));
           map.fitBounds(bounds);
           map.mapTypes.set('Styled', styledMapType);

       }
   }
</script>
```

I have 2 links:

```
- Atrakcja 1 pl
- Atrakcja 2 pl.
```

I would like to click on the links above to select the appropriate marker on Google Maps.

So if the user clicks on the link "Atrakcja 1 pl" - then the google map will show the marker Atrakcja 1 pll. I would like this marker on the map to be centered and his hint would be visible.

How can I do this in my code?

Please, help me.

Answer (score 1):

use `addmarker` function like this:

```
var markers = [
                        [
                          'Atrakcja 1 pl', 
                           51.73925413, 
                           19.51309225, 
                           'Atrakcja 1 pl', 
                           '#'
                         ],
                         [
                           'Atrakcja 2 PL', 
                            53.41475000, 
                            14.60220358, 
                           'Atrakcja 2 PL', 
                           '#'
                         ],
                     ];

function addmarker(point) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(point[1], point[2]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLang,
        title: point[0],
        draggable: true,
        map: map
    });
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition())
}

$('#obj-1').on('click', function() {
    addmarker(markers[0])
})

$('#obj-2').on('click', function() {
    addmarker(markers[1])
})
```

This code use `jquery`

add this to your html `head` tag

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

after setting the marker use

```
map.setCenter(marker.position);
marker.setMap(map);
```

and also you have to include the script to display map

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={YOUR_API_KEY}&callback={function}" async defer></script>
```